# Getting User Information in App Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have a web forms application.

I have integrated the App Insights SDK, I receive the notifications about the application like button click (through Custom Events, Track Event function) on my Azure portal.

How can I get user information like:

What regions/geography the user is logging from, which browser is he/she accessing through... things like that.

Right now, In Azure Portal under Usage--> Users

I get:

```
No data for 'users' with values of 'Country or region'.
```

Similarly, no data messages are there for sessions and page views even though for a Custom event (Button click), I am getting the metrics.

Please explain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get user information like:
>
> What regions/geography the user is logging from, which browser is he/she accessing through... things like that.

According to your description, I do a test to configure the chart under Application Insights > Overview > Metrics Explorer, and select the metrics and group metrics by **Browser version** or **Country or region**.

[image]

I set Chart type to Grid, and select Users and group by Country or region, the chart looks like this.

[image]

In a same way, I configure the chart to display Unique count of Users by Browser version, the chart looks like this.

[image]

> I get:
>
> No data for 'users' with values of 'Country or region'.

For “No data for 'users'…” issue, please make sure if you [add the scripts by hand](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-javascript/). And you could check “[No data on Page Views, Browsers, Usage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data/#q04)” section to troubleshoot no data issue.