# User information with Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am new to Microsoft Azure Application Insights and need some help on getting user information (Login ID, number of times user logged into application, etc). 
I went through another similar stack overflow post **[Getting User Information in App Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361016/getting-user-information-in-app-insights)** , but it did not helped me.

I have already setup Application Insights and getting the default data presented by Azure itself.

Request your help on the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you do, what are you trying to do, what didn't help?  you haven't presented enough specific information here.

Answer (score 0):

We did something similar to this using custom properties in our platform - this will be available for grouping in Azure portal as well.

Achievable by TrackPageViews in client side using AI script. With a small tweak:

```
appInsights.trackPageView("module_name", "serverUrl", {User: "UserName", DomainName: "Alias" });
```

Reference-Blog post written here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sample-mscrm

Comment: Thank you Arun for your reply. For a Web App, this is working perfectly fine. Please help me with below query too - 

I have implemented a Bot Solution using Microsoft Azure Bot Framework and enabled  Skype For Business Online Channel for it. I now want to use Application Insights to track the events such as ChatStart, ChatEnd and the number of chats initiated by an end user. Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: I saw your another post for this.. will follow there.. [mark as answer to help others]

Answer (score 0):

for something like "number times user logged into application" could be as simple as

```
union customEvents, pageViews
| where timestamp > ago(14d) 
| summarize numSessions = dcount(session_Id) by user_Id 
| top 100 by numSessions
```

(or in english, "in the last 14 days, show me top 100 users by how many sessions they have in events and page views")

depending on what telemetry you're sending, you'd adjust what tables you are using, what date/time ranges you want, if you want specific events or pages by names, etc.

or, you could use the Usage features in the portal, which can show you this kind of information.