# Does Azure Application Insights provide any built-ways to anonymize user data?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights

This question [User information with Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320728/user-information-with-application-insights)  demonstrates how to retrieve user-related information.

Does Azure Application Insights provide any built-ways to anonymize user data, either after the fact (run some process on existing data "in the cloud"), or as on the client API side (.NET) as data is getting sent to it?

Comment: what's the meaning of anonymize user data? do not send these user related data?

Comment: yes, "do not send/store these user related data", would be a good summary, but not knowing what the options are on the azure platform side, I am keeping the question as vague as possible.

Comment: at least, it cannot be changed for existing data in cloud. But not sure if we can do it on client as data is getting sent to app insights.

Answer (score 0):

You can write and configure plug-ins for the Application Insights SDK to customize how telemetry can be enriched and processed before it's sent to the Application Insights service.

Filtering with Telemetry Processors lets you filter out telemetry in the SDK before it is sent to the server. For example, you could reduce the volume of telemetry by excluding requests from robots. Filtering is a more basic approach to reducing traffic than sampling. It allows you more control over what is transmitted, but you have to be aware that it affects your statistics - for example, if you filter out all successful requests.

You can write the filtering logic and anonymize the data before sending it to the server.

Here is an example of dependency filter:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

public class SuccessfulDependencyFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // next will point to the next TelemetryProcessor in the chain.
    public SuccessfulDependencyFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        // To filter out an item, return without calling the next processor.
        if (!OKtoSend(item)) { return; }

        this.Next.Process(item);
    }

    // Example: replace with your own criteria.
    private bool OKtoSend (ITelemetry item)
    {
        var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;
        if (dependency == null) return true;

        return dependency.Success != true;
    }
}
```

You can read more about filter and sampling in below doc, see if it helps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling